# Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string

Tags: php

I'm working on my PHP to get the list of urls. I'm using domdocument to get the list of urls which I have got for the input and I want to send the request to each url to get the return strings.

When I tried this:

```
  if($link->getAttribute('href'))
  {
     if(!$link->hasAttribute('id') || $link->getAttribute('id')!='streams')
     {
       $url = str_replace("rtmp://", "", $link->getAttribute('href'));
       $url = str_replace(" ", "%20", $link->getAttribute('href'));
       echo $url;
       echo "<br>";
       $sdoc = new DOMDocument();
       $sdoc->strictErrorChecking = false;
       $sdoc->recover=true;
       @$sdoc->loadHTMLFile($url);
       $spans = $sdoc->getElementsByTagName('span');
       echo $spans;
     }
  }
```

I will get this: Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string.

The error are jumping on this line:

```
echo $spans;
```

Here is the list of time strings for each url that I want to parse:

```
<span id="time1">4:00 PM</span> - 
<span id="time2">4:30 PM</span> 
<span id="time3">5:00 PM</span> 
<span id="time4">5:30 PM</span>
<span id="time5">6:00 PM</span>
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;

$xml .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
$xml .= '
<tv generator-info-name="www.mysite.com/xmltv">';

$baseUrl = file_get_contents('http://http://www.mysite.com/get-listing.php');

$domdoc = new DOMDocument();
$domdoc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$domdoc->recover=true;
//@$domdoc->loadHTMLFile($baseUrl);
@$domdoc->loadHTML($baseUrl);

//$links = $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('test');
//$links = $domdoc->getElementById('test');
$links = $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('a');

$data = array();
foreach($links as $link)
{
  //echo $link->getAttribute('id, test');
  //echo $test;


  //echo $domdoc->saveXML($link);
  if($link->getAttribute('href'))
  {
     if(!$link->hasAttribute('id') || $link->getAttribute('id')!='streams')
     {
       $url = str_replace("rtmp://", "", $link->getAttribute('href'));
       $url = str_replace(" ", "%20", $link->getAttribute('href'));
       echo $url;
       echo "<br>";
       $sdoc = new DOMDocument();
       $sdoc->strictErrorChecking = false;
       $sdoc->recover=true;
       @$sdoc->loadHTMLFile($url);
       $spans = $sdoc->getElementsByTagName('span');
       $query = parse_url($url)['query'];
       $url_split = explode("&", $query)[0];
       $channel = urldecode(explode("=",$url_split)[1]);

       foreach($spans as $span)
       {
         $id = $span->getAttribute('time1');
         //echo $id;
       }
     }
  }
}
?>
```

Can you please tell me why I'm getting the catachable fatal error and how I can echo for the time strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not obvious what values you are trying to recieve, but if its the times, you can used `node->nodeValue` :

```
foreach($spans as $span)
   {
     echo $span->nodeValue;     
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are getting a list back, and it need to traverse it. Try this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $spans->length; $i++) {
   echo $spans->item($i)->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

and see if that doesn't help you get what you are looking for.

You can also just use foreach:

```
foreach ($spans as $time) {
    echo $time->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php